# Hive - Explode array column and use LEFT join or sub-query with select statement Error

Tags: sql, arrays, hadoop, hive, exploded

Given two tables:

`filtered_locations` containing small set of data (only a few rows)

```
|-------------|
| loc<String> | 
|-------------|
|     ...     |
|-------------|
```

`table_clients` very large table (**millions** rows)

```
 |--------------------------------------------|
 | id  | name|  age |locations <array<String> | 
 |-----|--------------------------------------|
 |     |     |      | [a,b,c..]               |
 |--------------------------------------------|
```

I want to query table `table_clients` for the value on `filtered_locations`.
  the main issue is that the field to query on the `table_clients` is an `array` type.

So, I exploded the column and then tried to embed a sub-query to include only the locations listed in  `filtered_locations`.

The first issue I faced is that Hive (at least the version I am running) seems not to accept a sub query insoide the `in` or `exists` statment.

That's the error I get:

> Error while compiling statement:  FAILED: SemanticException Invalid
>   column reference 'location' in definition of SubQuery  sq_1 [
>   tc.location in ( select fl.loc from filtered_locations fl ) ] used as
>   sq_1

As an alternative I tried to use a `LEFT JOIN` but also does not work because of the `explode` call
Second error

> Error while compiling statement:  FAILED: SemanticException [Error
>   10085]: JOIN with a LATERAL VIEW is not supported 'location'

```
with filtered_locations as (
  SELECT
    'loc1' as loc
    union all
    'loc2' as loc
)

select 
  id, name, location
  max(age) as max_age 
from
  table_clients tc
  LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(locations) l as location
-- Ideally this should work!
-- where
--  tc.location in (
--     select fl.loc from filtered_locations fl
--  )
left join filtered_locations fl
on fl.loc = tc.location

group by id, name, location
```

What is then the best solution for my problem? Note that the `table_clients` has millions of records!

Thanks

Comment: There is no `tc.location`, there is `l.location`

Comment: "very large table (millions rows)"? Seriously?

Comment: `tc.location` IS the exploded column for tc.locations array column. You don't consider this tale big?

Comment: **(1)** No, the EXPLODE relation alias is `l`, so  it is `l.location` **(2)** Local databases (SQL Server, PostgreSQL, Oracle etc.), installed on a standard personal computer, process millions of records in seconds. You don't go to Hive for millions of records.

Comment: The table has millions and millions of records, anyway even `l.location` does not work. Read the errors first

Comment: **(1)** I don't get "millions and millions". 10th millions? 100ds millions? Billion? **(2)** What does not work? The `in` version? What is the error message?

Comment: Yes, several millions, maybe billions and this per partition. The table is large! Anyway, this is not the point. Please read the question if you want to help.

Comment: By the way, the work around was to  do another sub-select with the relevant columns from `table_clients ` and then perform the `left join` on that sub-select. This works, but the performance is not that good.

Comment: You have ignored the 2nd thing I wrote

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, this should have worked

```
select  *

from    table_clients c
        lateral view explode(location) e as loc

where   e.loc in (select l.loc from filtered_locations l)
;
```

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10009]: Line 6:8 Invalid table alias
>   'e'

... but since it does not, a little work-around is needed

```
select  *

from   (select  *

        from    table_clients c
                lateral view explode(location) e as loc
        ) c        

where   c.loc in (select l.loc from filtered_locations l)
;
```

Comment: Yes, that was also my solution. My concern was that since `table_clients` is large and I only need to filter a few records this approach makes it a bit slow, but well, it works :). Thanks

Comment: Having a sub-query does not necessarily means having an additional step. This is what optimizers are for. Do you think there is a difference between `select * from(select * from(select * from(select * from(select * from t)t)t)t)t;` and `select * from t`?

Comment: Hum, I see. so there is not, much loss on performance in having the sub-query after the `select * from clients` plus the explode? thanks for bringing this up. I actually do not know much about how SQL engines optimize the queries. Tx